# Form is getting submitted even if email exist in database...How to clear email field and ask user to enter non existing email ID

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

The following code only alerts the user if the email is existing or not. How should I prevent user from submitting form
//This is view create.php

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
            $('#email').change(function()
            {
                var email = $("#email").val();

                var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
                if(email!='')
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url: "<?php echo site_url('welcome/email_availabilty'); ?>",

                        data:{ email:email },
                        success:function(data)
                        {   
                            if(data)
                            {
                                alert('Email Already Exists');

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                alert('Email Available');
                            } 
                        },
                        return false;
                        error: function(e){
                            console.log(e);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

//This is controler welcome.php

```
  function email_availabilty()
   {

        $res=$_POST['email'];
        $this->load->model('queries');
        $data=$this->queries->email_available($res);
        echo $data;
    }
```

//this is model queries.php

```
public function email_available($res)  
    {

        $data=$this->db->query("select email from tbl_posts where email='$res'");
        if($data->num_rows() >= 1)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Please tell me how to prevent user from submitting form if email is already existing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you're not preventing the default behaviour of the browser by using [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) or `return` with either `false` or `true` accordingly.

```
function [...](e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    [...]
}
```

You should also have a syntax error because of the random `return false;` you have in you AJAX code.

Change,

```
success:function(data) {   
    if(data) {
        alert('Email Already Exists');

    } else {
        alert('Email Available');
    } 
},
return false; <---- Here...
```

to,

```
success:function(data) {   
    if(data) {
        alert('Email Already Exists');

    } else {
        alert('Email Available');
    }

    return false; <---- Here...
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank You, guys!
I got solution 
By adding '$("#email").val('');' after

alert('Email Already Exists');

Answer (score 0):

You should disable with jQuery the `Send` button of the form if the email already exists.

Even better, you should only enable it if the email does not exist.